# How to customize network name in docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose

```
    version: '3.8'
    
    services:
      foo:
        ...
        networks:
          - $FOO_NETWORK

networks:
  foo_network:
```

I am unable to use $FOO_NETWORK under networks, i.e. it allows only to enter a value and not an ENV variable. How do I customize the network name to be taken from the environment variable instead

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).You could create a `.env` file at the same level as your `docker-compose.yml` file and then you could specify it when running a command, example: `docker-compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev up`

Comment: The foo_network: under networks section is not customizable, hence the question

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) specify that: `When you run docker-compose up with this configuration, Compose looks for the environment variable in the shell and substitutes its value in.` So I don't know, do you want to to evaluate environment variable or take the name of the network specified in the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: If you look at the syntax at the bottom for networks: it is mentioned as foo_network: so I cannot replace this as $FOO_NETWORK: This doesn't work

Comment: I couldn't find any information if variable substitution is possible for a key. Maybe as a workaround you could create a network separately and then refer to it inside `docker-compose.yml` as an external network by it's name?

Answer (score 3):

Environment variables are for values, you want to use it for a key. As far as i know this isn't supported yet and I'm not sure if it'll ever be.

One way you can customise this is to use multiple docker-compose files. Create three files:

**one.yml**:

```yaml
version: "3.0"

services:
  test:
    image: nginx
```

**two.yml**:

```yaml
version: "3.0"

services:
  test:
    networks:
      foo: {}

networks:
  foo: {}
```

**three.yml**:

```yaml
version: "3.0"

services:
  test:
    networks:
      bar: {}

networks:
  bar: {}
```

Now you if you run it like this:

```sh
docker-compose -f one.yml -f two.yml up
```

or like this:

```sh
docker-compose -f one.yml -f three.yml up
```

You'll see that the files are merged:

```
Creating network "network_foo" with the default driver
Recreating network_test_1 ... done
...
Creating network "network_bar" with the default driver
Recreating network_test_1 ... done
```

You can even spin all three at once:

```
docker-compose -f one.yml -f two.yml -f three.yml up
Creating network "network_foo" with the default driver
Creating network "network_bar" with the default driver
Creating network_test_1 ... done
Attaching to network_test_1
test_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
```

Check out documentation for more: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Also there is another way, which actually involves using variables to select a network. The way is to use **existing networks**. You'll need an `.env` file for this:

```
network=my_network
```

and in compose file you do like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  test:
    networks:
      mynet: {}

networks:
  mynet:
    external: true
    name: $network
```

As you see there is an option to provide `name` when using an external network. The network with the `name` must exist when you start your containers or you'll get an error. You can use a separate file to create networks on a node or just create using CLI. Note that the compose version changed, the feature isn't supported in "3.0".